# Use "findViewById" repetitively or store View?

Tags: android, findviewbyid

Being the efficiency freak that I am (as I'm sure lots of you all are as well), I've wondered this for a while and just thought of posing this question:

Two scenarios, possibly two different answers.

If I'm looping through a list of items and updating a bunch of EditTexts in a LinearLayout as such, what are the pros/cons of these two methods:
1)

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
    ((TextView)findViewById(itemList.get(i).getId())).setText(itemList.getText());
    ((TextView)findViewById(itemList.get(i).getId())).setColor(itemList.getColor());
}
```

2)

```
TextView tv;
for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
    tv = ((TextView)findViewById(itemList.get(i).getId()));
    tv.setText(itemList.getText());
    tv.setColor(itemList.getColor());
}
```

I think the underlying question is how efficient is "findViewById"? This may be picky, I think 2) is the better solution. Thanks!

Comment: `findViewById` is kinda expensive. **2)** only calls it 1 time. So it's better than **1)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not picky at all. 2nd option is without doubt the better one.

**1**

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
    ((TextView)findViewById(itemList.get(i).getId())).setText(itemList.getText());
    ((TextView)findViewById(itemList.get(i).getId())).setColor(itemList.getColor());
}
```

Looks clean, but isn't. If you are working with one and the same textview, absolutely do not call findViewById more than once.

**2**

```
TextView tv;
for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
    tv = ((TextView)findViewById(itemList.get(i).getId()));
    tv.setText(itemList.getText());
    tv.setColor(itemList.getColor());
}
```

This is the better option, because it only calls findViewById once. It's a little less readable, though.

You could also consider a 3rd option

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
    TextView tv = ((TextView)findViewById(itemList.get(i).getId()));
    tv.setText(itemList.getText());
    tv.setColor(itemList.getColor());
}
```

This keeps everything in the loop (easier to read, imo) without notably sacrificing efficiency. I prefer the 3rd, but the 2nd is a good pick as well.

Comment: Interesting, my perception was that creating a new TextView within the loop is less efficient (it seems that is the case since you said "notably"). I'm now wondering how much less efficient is it?

Comment: @TomMcFarlin a TextView is only a small UI Element, mobile devices nowadays have good enough processors that you won't notice the difference. I have no number to prove how much more or less efficient they are, but if you are in doubt, you can just go with the 2nd option :-)

Answer (score 2):

With your second option you save:
- A call to findViewById()
- A call to itemList.get(i)
- A call to [itemList.get(i)] getId()

Also, note that in a for loop usually going backward is a little bit faster (more optimized) than going forward (because i < value translates to i-value < 0, which is more expensive than i > 0).

Answer (score 1):

A google employee Dianne Hackborn has answered a very similar question [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/_22Z90dshoM/-Da3rpSlBm8J).

She says that you should avoid using `findViewByid` repetitevely whenever you can.

Answer (score 0):

I think without doubt the second option is better.
Not only you save the cost of calling findViewById one extra time (ok at the cost of one extra local variable)
but the code is also much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use new `RecyclerView` if possible now. Combined with `LinearLayoutManager` it'll allow you achieve the same, but you'll be forced to use `ViewHolder` pattern. 
If you go with your `ListView`, you should also implement `ViewHolder`. `findViewById` is definitely not efficient, so you need to prevent too many calls to it.

Answer (score 0):

**Second** way is better, because the cost of findViewById() is acceptable in **static UI layouts**. However, since getView() is called **frequently**, the usage of findViewById() should be kept to **minimum**.

Answer (score 0):

The second is for sure less expensive by 50%. 
But I would prefer @TimCastelijns 3rd method because he is dumping the view reference at the end of the loop.

In the first method, you use `findViewById` twice. 
In the second method, you use it once and save a reference to it, which saves 50% off of the resource usage.

I preferred @TimCastelijns, because he saves it as a local variable, which will be dumped, therefore saving resources.

Comment: Please provide additional information that supports your claim.